# Concatenate unsigned char[] value and convert to char *

Tags: c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm using Java NDK in order to extract some info from a "bin" file using a C struct. I have to extract info about a gateway, in for loop. I'm able to extract info, but I need to concatenate the results and add dot `.` in order to print the final IP and convert it to `char*` or `string`.
I used `reinterpret_cast` but it doesn't work.

How can I convert the IP address to a string?

```
#define  LOGD(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)

//Gateway.info[4] is unsigned char type
int config_len = sizeof(ptr->Gateway.info);
for (int i = 0; i < config_len; i++) {
    int number = ptr->Gateway.info[i];

}
LOGD("GATEWAY %d",number);
```

---

Comment: Is `LOGD` using [`printf` (or one of its siblings)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)? Then the format to print a `char` as a small integer is `"%hhd"`. Or `"%hhu"` for `unsigned char`.

Comment: yes it uses printf format.

Comment: The problem is the use of `reinterpret_cast` because the C language doesn't have that feature.  Maybe you should update your language tags correctly.

Comment: Which language C or C++?  In C++ you could use `std::ostringstream`, which is not in the C language.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews  `c++`. 
I used both method but when I print string is empty.
- Method 1`std::string sName(reinterpret_cast<char*>(ptr->Gateway.info));`

- Method 2`int number; string Result;  ostringstream convert;  convert << Number;    
Result = convert.str();`

Comment: I made a mistake. I solved with the second method. Thanks to all. :)

Comment: Does your modified question above now include the answer? If so, please roll it back and add the solution as an answer below - that will make more sense to future readers.

Comment: Ok . I'll Change :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake. It works!

```
#define  LOGD(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)


string Result; 
ostringstream convert;

//Gateway.info[4] is unsigned char type
int config_len = sizeof(ptr->Gateway.info);
for (int i = 0; i < config_len; i++) {
    int number = ptr->Gateway.info[i];
    convert << number; 
    Result = convert.str()

}
```

Comment: It looks like this is the best answer. If you think so, go ahead and accept it.

Comment: But, I think you should move the `Result = ` out to below the loop. It only needs to be called once.